# PHPUnit: How to create unit test to test foreach that using the private function result

Tags: php, unit-testing

I am new to PHPUnit , I need to write an test that takes the result from the private access pass on to next foreach.

// PHP code

```
function processReport(){

$customerList = $this->getCustomerList();

foreach ($customerList as $each=>$customerData){

  }
}
```

//PHP unit test code trying

```
$report->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getCustomerList')
        ->will($this->returnValueMap(array('0'=>array('id'=>'665'))));

    $report->processReport($options);
```

I am getting error like "invalid argument supplied foreach".

Please guide to solve this.. Thanks in advance